# How to count number of lines?

Tags: c

How to only count the number of lines in the input, without affecting further process?

I was using the following function to get the number of lines in the input,
but after that, I can't do anything more cause all those characters were like "consumed".

```
int count_line(){
    int i, lines = 0;
    while ((i = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if ( i == '\n') {
            lines ++;
         }
    }
    return lines;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You either need to start again from begin of your file or you need to integrate that counting into your processing of the file content.

Comment: You could save them somewhere so you can re-access them.

Comment: @Gerhardh: Rewinding to the start of the file is generally not an option when reading from `stdin`.

Comment: I believe that this question may be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why do you want to count the number of lines **before** processing the data, instead of **while** processing the data?

Comment: Thanks, guys! I will try to count lines while processing.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel sure, you are right. I missed that `stdin` is used.